# Application upload issue in bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-plugin

When pushing my application to bluemix with cf cli, it is showing  "0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting"...and after sometime "FAILED start app timeout"

For the same account, in eclipse ibm bluemix server is not starting.

Comment: Please post logs so we can help you. `> cf logs --recent`

Comment: no such error in logs also

Comment: Well then how are we going to help you?

Comment: Rahul, you probably have to push your application again and then run the logs immediately after the push fails for the `cf logs appname --recent` command to display results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ram,
We contacted the IBM customer support for the same problem and they suggested us to use a different buildpack.

This cf command prints the available buildpacks list for liberty runtime:
    cf buildpacks | grep -i liberty

It returns 2 buildpack options
To specify the buildpack

```
cf push appName -b buildPackName
```

Hope this will help others.

Comment: Could you specify which application's specs suggested to use a different buildpack and which is the buildpack working?

Comment: There were 2 buildpacks listed after running the command.
First was liberty-for-java_v2_3-20151208-1311 and second was liberty-for-java. 

We then ran the second command  with liberty-for-java